# Prove that $ \lim_{x\to c} f(x) =L$ then $\lim_{x\to c} af(x) =aL$ for any real number a.

Tags: real-analysis

Problem

Suppose that $f : D → \mathbb{R}$ and that $c$ is an accumulation point of $D$. Prove that $$\lim_{x\to c} f(x) =L$$ then $$\lim_{x\to c} af(x) =aL$$ for any real number a.

---

Theorems/Lemmas I think of using

Theorem1: Let $x0$ be an accumulation point of $D ⊂ R$, then the following statements are equivalent

**Statement 1**: The function $f(x)$ has a limit,$L$ at $x_0$.

**Statement 2**: If $\{x_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$is a sequence of elements of D, none equal to $x_0$ but convergent
to $x_0$, then the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ converges to L.

Theorem2: The Arithmetic of Function Limits: Suppose $f, g : A → \mathbb{R}$ with $c$ an
accumulation point of $A$, and further suppose that $f$ and $g$ have limits at $c$.Then The function $fg$ has a limit at $c$ and
$$\lim_{x\to c} (fg)(x) = \lim_{x\to c}f(x)  · \lim_{x\to c}g(x) $$

Lemma:Let $\{x_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ be a sequence such that, for some $N ∈ \mathbb{N}$, $x_n = α$ for $n ≥ N $. Prove that $\{x_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ converges to $α$

---

I needed help proving this question. It seems easy enough given $a$ is just a constant, however I doubt the proof is that simple of using invariance under positive scaling on both sides. I was thinking more along the lines of using the results of the lemma and consequently the theorem 1 we get two sequences, thus by theorem 2 we get our conclusion.

---

Proof: Given $$\lim_{x\to c} f(x) =L$$, thus by Theorem1

$\{f(x_n)\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ converges to L

, Furthermore given $a$ be any real number, by lemma

$\{a\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ converges to a.

therefore by theorem 2. 
$$\lim_{x\to c} af(x) =aL$$

---

I am open to feedback, I would also love to see your variation of the proof. I love to see how others word their proofs.

Comment: Your proof is fine. An alternative, more direct route would be $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) =L$ means that $\forall x >0, \exists \delta >0 \,$ such that $|x-c| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$, so that $|x-c| < \delta \implies |af(x) - aL| = a|f(x) - L| < a\epsilon$ which can be made arbitrarily small (you can formalize this by dividing by $a$ in the appropriate spot and writing this as a direct proof)